# How to aggregate data.table on multiple dimensoins

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table for which I want to aggregate the data based on multiple fields. Here is a simplified example of my data:

```
# each record is the number of pages read
# by a student in a given day
pages_per_day <- data.table(
  student_id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
  week_of_semester = c(1,1,2,1,2,2),
  pages_read = c(8,6,4,7,8,7)
)
```

I would like to aggregate this data based on both student_id and week to show the average number of pages per each student read during a given week of the semester. I tried the following:

```
avg_weekly_pages_read <- grades[,list(
  avg_pages = sum(pages_read) / .N,
  by = c('student_id','week')
)]
```

This gives me a two column data table with columns: avg_pages, by.

I was hoping to have a table more like:

```
student_id, week, avg_pages
1,1,7
1,2,4
2,1,7
2,2,7.5
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest starting with the *Introduction to data.table* HTML vignette [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started)..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll be sure to read through it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for

```
pages_per_day[, .(avg_pages = mean(pages_read)), by = .(student_id, week_of_semester)]
#    student_id week_of_semester avg_pages
# 1:          1                1       7.0
# 2:          1                2       4.0
# 3:          2                1       7.0
# 4:          2                2       7.5
```

Btw, no need to reinvent the wheel. There is a `mean` functions in R

Comment: Thanks David. With the exception that the .() syntax didn't work for me this worked perfectly. Instead I used c() and everything worked great.

Comment: What `data.table` version you have? This should work with the latest one.

Answer (score -2):

```
 aggregate(pages_read~student_id+week_of_semester,pages_per_day,mean)
student_id week_of_semester pages_read
# 1          1                1        7.0
# 2          2                1        7.0
# 3          1                2        4.0
# 4          2                2        7.5
```

Comment: Fyi, the downvotes (not from me) are because the asker seems to want an answer with `data.table` syntax

Comment: I'd add to what Frank said - it's not just about having a `data.table` answer. If your answer was more elegant or faster or some other pluses going for it, it would get upvoted.